# Android App Using Android Studio

Tags: android, jboss-developer-studio

I need your attention a bit.

I am an electrical engineer and i was working on a home Automation Project using GSM Module.
Working:
When ever I will do text from a registered number to the SIM which is in the GSM Module It turns on/off the lights, and it will also send the temperature value.

Here all I need is to make an android app,through which i will just press the button and then then it automatically send a sms like"Turn Light One On'' to the GSM SIM MODULE and button should be appears like "Turn Light One On". Ease of convenience is that i don't want to type the long text again and again when ever i want to turn on/off the light and i just want to do this by pressing a simple button. 
When the  light turned on and button on app should be appears as light turn one off.

Comment: Is there a question? [ask]

Comment: How can i make that app which i required?

Comment: From the very beginning? Try the courses / tutorials & learning materials mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info - that will bring you to the point where you can make apps with buttons that do things. Then look for solutions to specific problems that remain. Like how to communicate with your module, how to send sms and so on. At that point, you'll find this site helpful.